# How to disable PhpStorm expanding on typing space in HTML mode?

Tags: phpstorm

When I edit a file with the ".html" extension I get the following behaviour:

When I type the word "in" inside a tag followed by a space or equal sign, it is expanded to "inlist". When I type the word "in" inside a tags attribute followed by a blank, it is expanded to "{settings} ".

Is there an option to achieve, that those expansions only happen, when I hit the TAB-key?

Comment: See what you have got there: `Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Emmet`. If it's not `Space`, also check the same in `Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Live Templates`. If it's also not there, then check your `Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | General | Code Completion` and look for the option related to Space.

Comment: Thanks. Yes macOS. 

The first to options are set to "Tab". In the "Code Completion" window there is only a <Ctrl><Shift><Space> combination and nothing else related to Space.

Comment: I disabled some plugins. Seems the vue.js plugin is the culprit. Yet I don't know if it causes the expansion behaviour or just delivers the abbreviations.

Comment: is *Insert selected suggestion by pressing space, dot, or other context-dependent keys* enabled in *Preferences | Editor | General | Code Completion*?